# Dark Souls 3 on wine

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

Wanted to play Dark Souls 3 on Ubuntu. Am using Wine and PlayonLinux. 
I get an error while installing : 
Title - Isdone.dll
Text - An error occured while unpacking: Unable to write data to disk!
Unarc.dll returned an error code -11
ERROR: Can't open file C:\Program Files (x86)\Dark Souls III\Original Soundtrack\02-Dark Souls - Yuka Kitamura.mp3

Note that if I try on windows ,I can sucessfully install and play the game.